# Cannot list array in alfresco freemarker template

Tags: alfresco, freemarker

I am having big problems to get my webscript working. Best thing is that ín the Alfresco JavaScript Console everything is working. Not if I deploy the webscript.

javascript:

```
try {

var nodeRefs = args[0].split('&');
var paths = [];
for (var n in nodeRefs) {
    var doc = search.findNode(nodeRefs[n]);
    var path = doc.displayPath + "/" + doc.name;
    var host = headers['Host'];
    path = path.replace('/Firmen-Home/Sites', '');
    path = path.replace('/Companyhome/Sites', '');
    path = path.replace(/\//g, '\\');
    paths.push("\\\\" + host + "@7070\\alfresco" + path);
}

model.paths = paths;
model.nodeRefs = nodeRefs;

} catch (e) {

}
```

freemarker template:

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
<#assign nodeRefs = nodeRefs>
{
<#assign n = 0>
<#list paths as path>
"${nodeRefs[n]}" : "${path}"<#if path_has_next>,</#if>
<#assign n = n + 1>
</#list>
}
</#escape>
```

JavaScript Console Output (I used the same noderef 3 times for testing):

```
{
   "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/5fa74ad3-9b5b-461b-9df5-de407f1f4fe7" : "\\\\localhost:8080@7070\\alfresco\\swsdp\\documentLibrary\\Budget Files\\budget.xls",
   "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/5fa74ad3-9b5b-461b-9df5-de407f1f4fe7" : "\\\\localhost:8080@7070\\alfresco\\swsdp\\documentLibrary\\Budget Files\\budget.xls",
   "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/5fa74ad3-9b5b-461b-9df5-de407f1f4fe7" : "\\\\localhost:8080@7070\\alfresco\\swsdp\\documentLibrary\\Budget Files\\budget.xls"
   }
```

I get 3 different Errors from the deployed webscripts at all possible solutions I tried:

> freemarker.core.ParseException - Encountered "{" at line 1, column 19 in convert/uuidsToPaths.get.json.ftl. Was expecting one of: "in" ... ">"
>
> freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 3, column 9 in convert\uuidsToPaths.get.json.ftl nodeRefs is undefined. It cannot be assigned to nodeRefs
>
> Expected collection or sequence. paths evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleHash

What am I mussing here? I tried `${nodeRefs}`, `$nodeRefs`, `{nodeRefs}` .... but nothing seems to work.

Regards,
Michael

EDIT:

JavaScript Controler:

```
function main() {

    var nodeRefs = args[0].split("_");
    var paths = [ nodeRefs.length ];
    var i = 0;

    for ( var n in nodeRefs) {
        var doc = search.findNode(nodeRefs[n]);
        var path = doc.displayPath + "/" + doc.name;
        var host = headers["Host"];
        paths[i] = "\\" + host + "@7070\alfresco\\" + path;
        i++;
    }

    model.code = "200";
    model.paths = paths;
    model.nodeRefs = nodeRefs;

}
main();
```

Freemarker JSON

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
    {
        "status" : {
            "code" : ${code} // easier to differ success from error
            },
        <#assign n = 0>
        <#list paths as path>
        "${nodeRefs[n]}" : "${path}"<#if path_has_next>,</#if>
        <#assign n = n + 1>
        </#list>
    }
</#escape>
```

Comment: For what "possible solutions" do you get which error? The syntax is `${someExpression}`, the other two is just static text and will be printed as is.

Comment: Why are you using `#assign` for nodeRefs since you already got the array stored in your `model.nodeRefs`? Also: the error seems to be pointing out your `paths` sequence is not a proper array but a simplehash. It could be that your array is stored with keys and values instead of solo values like: `paths[0].value = \\\\localhost` and `path[0].key = 8080@7070\\alfresco\\swsdp\\documentLibrary\\Budget Files\\budget.xls`. Try to check that. Btw, the correct syntax for index seq is: `${seq[n]}`

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! `nodeRefs` is just an array which stores an unknown amount of noderefs). @Alch3mi5t how else can I dynamically creat and extend an array where the size of it can differ for each call?

Comment: Using `<#assign nodeRefs = ${nodeRefs}>` throws `freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "{" at line 2, column 19`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really the answer, but the discussion in your comment isn't looking promising.

First of all, remove the try/catch element in the JavaScript so that you will actually see the error in your alfresco.log/share.log. *In your case I wouldn't even add a try/catch, the variables will be empty which will throw an error in Freemarker.*

```
<#assign nodeRefs = nodeRefs>
```

This is assigning an already available variable to itself which makes no sense at all :).
For your information all the `model.<variable>` are mapped and thus assigned to Freemarker variables.

So in your case **model.nodeRefs** in the controller JavaScript becomes **nodeRefs** in Freemarker.

Second remove the `<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>` in the Freemarker so your matching error doesn't mess up the linings (you should add it later on, once it's working).

The main error in your log file is:

> freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 3, column 9
>   in convert\uuidsToPaths.get.json.ftl nodeRefs is undefined. It cannot
>   be assigned to nodeRefs

This means the model.nodeRefs doesn't exists en thus your JavaScript has thrown an error which it doesn't show in the log.

Comment: Hell yeah! Thank you very much this helped me understanding freemarker a bit better! Its working now. You were right, the variable nodeRefs was empty/not a valid array!